# Java Unit Test Verify ServletOutputStream

Tags: java, servlets, junit4

I have written a JUnit4 unit test to verify servlet response, the servlet response has two additional fields, which corresponds to `0` and length of the byte stream. These are not added in the servlet call, may be it is done internally.

I couldn't add the integer to byte array for comparison. Every items are compared as byte array. How to verify servlet response in a unit test?

```
@Mock
private HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

@Mock
private HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse;

@Mock
private ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream;


@Test
public void testOutputStream() throws Exception {

    when(httpServletResponse.getOutputStream()).thenReturn(servletOutputStream);

    // Invoke servlet call
    doGet.invoke(handle, httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);

    // Verify output stream
    verify(servletOutputStream).write(out.getBytes());
}
```

Argument(s) are different! Wanted:

servletOutputStream.write(
    [(byte) 0x23, (byte) 0x45, (byte) 0x58, (byte) 0x54, (byte) 0x4D, (byte) 0x33, (byte) 0x55, (byte) 0x0A, (byte) 0x23, (byte) 0x45]
);

Actual invocation has different arguments:

servletOutputStream.write(
    [(byte) 0x23, (byte) 0x45, (byte) 0x58, (byte) 0x54, (byte) 0x4D, (byte) 0x33, (byte) 0x55, (byte) 0x0A, (byte) 0x23, (byte) 0x45],
0, 10
);

Comment: You shouldn't care how the bytes are written to the stream: that's an implementation detail. What you should care about is which bytes are being written to the stream. Pass a real stream instead of a mock (a ByteArrayOutputStream, for example), and then check that the bytes contained in the ByteArrayOutputStream are the bytes that you expect.

Comment: @Nizet Thanks for the suggestion. I have passed a custom `ServletOutputStream`  instead of a Mock which helped.

Comment: @JBNizet `ByteArrayOutputStream` unfortunately doesn't satisfy the type `ServletOutputStream`, and cannot be used directly.